# Chrome select options list detaches on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I have jQuery code that scrolls the page on the way that the selected control is in the middle of screen.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.select').click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: 100
    }, 100);
    return false;
 });
});
```

Unfortunately Chrome (ver 31.0.1650.63 ) causes that the options list is detached if document is scrolled after select where expanded. Working fine in FF(25/26)  and IE 10/11. [Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nikalaj4o/4YaPq/1/)

Comment: I feel like you're going to have to prevent the select list from opening on click, do the animation, then trigger the list to open again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best I could do is this : http://jsbin.com/ANiMacem/3/edit

Add this function :

```
function openSelect(obj) {

    var element = obj[0];
    if (document.createEvent) { // all browsers
        var e = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
        e.initMouseEvent("mousedown", true, false, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
        element.dispatchEvent(e);
    } else
    if (element.fireEvent) { // ie
        element.fireEvent("onmousedown");
    }
}
```

And change your code to :

```
  $(".select").on('click',function() {

            $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: 100
        }, 100);

       setTimeout(function (){ openSelect($(".select"));
                               openSelect($(".select")); //yes twice.
                             },100);


         return false;
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for the hack Royi. Any idea for the reason - Chrome bug?

Comment: Well i dont know but if its bother you so much and only in chrome , so it is ok to use a hack for 1 rare case of scroll on  ddl with chrome 31 . I